# Precision of PositionAlongLine

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, cursor

When I execute this code:
`list1 = [2500, 4600, 6500, 7500, 10500, 12500, 14500, 16000, 17500, 19000, 20500, 22500, 24500, 26500, 29500, 31500, 33500, 35900, 37500, 39500, 41500, 43200, 45500, 47500, 49200, 51500, 53500, 55500, 58000] 
for i in list1:
    for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor('shapefile.shp', ["SHAPE@"]):
        uu = (i/60910.0)
        print uu
        point = row[0].positionAlongLine(uu, True)
        cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor('pointsshp.shp', ("SHAPE@"))
        cursor.insertRow([point])
        del cursor`
Then the 1st point is 2800 meters instead of 2500 meters from the start of the line. All points are not precise - I can understand a few meters but not 300 meters! The line is 6910 meters long for sure. Both shapefiles are in GCS_WGS_1984 and the data frame is projected to WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_33N.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the UTM projection to the cursor.

```
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(32633)  # wkid for WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_33N
... 
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor('shapefile.shp', ['SHAPE@'], spatial_reference=sr):
    ...
```

This might make a difference.